# Custom filter makes built in filter not work in react table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using react-table v7. I have this columns and this custom filter. When the multiSelectFilter is set for accessor 'name' the 'between' filter stops working. When I remove the multiSelectFilter it works fine.

```
    function multiSelectFilter(rows, columnIds, filterValues) {
        return filterValues.length === 0
            ? rows
            : rows.filter(row => {
                const cellValue = String(row.original[columnIds]).toLowerCase();
                return filterValues.some((filterValue) => cellValue.includes(filterValue));
            });
    }

const columns = [{
        Header: 'Nome',
        accessor: 'name',
        filter: multiSelectFilter,
    },
    {
        Header: 'Instituição',
        accessor: 'company'
    },
    {
        Header: 'Latitude',
        accessor: 'lat',
        filter: 'between',
        Cell: ({ value }) => Number(value).toFixed(2)
    }]
```

I tried to create a custom between filter but it also doesn't work. How can I use this two filters together?